# How to write the type constraint of the following code

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
interface IRouteProps {
  path: string
  name: string
}

const routesConfig: IRouteProps[] = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login'
  }
];

let routeNames: any;

const routes: IRouteProps[] = routesConfig.forEach((route: IRouteProps) => {
    routeNames[route.name] = route.path;
});
```

I want to get the value of each object from an array of objects, and then use this value as the key for another object.

If you use typescript to constrain the type of this new object, how do you write it?

How to write the type constraint of 'routeNames'?

Comment: The specific values aren't typed, only the type of the values (strings), so `{ [name: string]: string }`?

Comment: My original intention is to want a code hint. For example, in webstrom or vscode, when calling 'routeNames', it can prompt the key-value pairs already in this object. So I need a type to constrain this variable.

Comment: Unless they're hard-coded, and they don't look it, given the `: string`s, it's not possible, because they're dynamic, done by JS, after TS has finished compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type is not very specific, as name and path are strings. So the structure which you can model from it is:

```
type RoutesMap = Record<IRouteProps['name'], IRouteProps['path']>
```

what really is equivalent to:

```
type RoutesMap = Record<string, string>
```

Now to create such instead of `foreach`, we should use `reduce`( yes yes, we can use foreach also, but not as an expression as it was in original code sample):

```
const routes = routesConfig.reduce((routes, route: IRouteProps) => {
    routes[route.name] = route.path;
    return routes;
}, {} as RoutesMap);
```

But the type we will get is only map `string: string`. We can go more specific by for example `const` keyword. Consider:

```
const routesConfig = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login'
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard'
  }
] as const; // pay attention here

type IRouteProps = typeof routesConfig[number];
type RoutesMap = Record<IRouteProps['name'], IRouteProps['path']>

const routes = routesConfig.reduce((routes, route: IRouteProps) => {
    routes[route.name] = route.path;
    return routes;
}, {} as RoutesMap);
```

In this case `RoutesMap` is specified to values existing in routesConfig object.

Comment: Thank you very much, the ideas you provided were very useful to me.